# How to type पत्ते with half त् as in त्य

Tags: culture, sanskrit, tradition, resource, language

I know this is not directly related to Hinduism but as this community seems to have a background of typing in in Devnaagari / Hindi / Sanskrit. I have searched a lot. I hope someone will answer...

I want to type words like उत्तर or पत्ते with half त् + त but all fonts I have generate half त् as just a line over त ( - + त = त्त)

I would like to type it like the त् present in त्य
Why does ( त् + य = त्य ) type correctly but ( त् + त = त्त ) types with just a line over त?

Can someone point me towards the right Font for Hindi which can solve my problem?

I have tried all Devnaagari Fonts on Google Fonts and only [Modak](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Modak?subset=devanagari&preview.text=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0&preview.text_type=custom#standard-styles) types the right way.
[image: Image displaying the way Modak types]

Comment: That is correct. These glyphs are defined in font files and you should pick the right one for your taste. Or create one.

Comment: I have seen many Government Textbooks (NCERT/CBSE) which type the half त् the way I require, which font do you think might be used by these institutions?

Comment: Book prints likely use different glyphs , specially created by them. Proprietary fonts are common. Also, books are not necessarily created as soft documents.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Please use [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for general discussion on Hinduism. Currently this question does not come in the scope of the site. This makes it off-topic.